# PDF Option Not Coming In Windows Printer Created

Tags: windows, pdf, printer

I have created a local pdf printer under windows with following settings :

[image: Settings - Tab 1]

[image: Settings - Tab 2]

However, when I sent a print to pdf printer, I get this dialog box .

[image: No PDF Option]

As you can see, there is no PDF option in circled drop down. Moreover, when I click on dropdown, it shows blank. So the user has to manually add ".pdf" extenstion after file name

What settings should I do such that "Save as Type": PDF  --> option is visible in the drop down

Answer (score 1):

It's a strnge setup.  I would had said it was wrong, and you might have to look at the setup again.

My pfd printer creates a port, and spools the printed pages into a pre-pdf file, you then create the PDF by saving the spool.

Generic/text-only refers to the sort of character-mode typewriter style printers.  It won't print graphics or fancy fonts, for example,

See, eg http://www.howtogeek.com/150891/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-windows-4-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: can you please give me steps as to how did you create a pdf printer ?

Comment: You can't just save the file as a PDF and expect it to work.  You have to find a "PDF print driver", or failing that, 'save as pdf' extension for the application you are using.

It's better to get a 'save as pdf', because it preserves a lot of the structure of the document, where these have to be included in a PDF print driver.  

http://www.howtogeek.com/150891/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-windows-4-tips-and-tricks/